# How to get Weather info using google weather api when I have longitude and latitude co-ordinates?

Tags: iphone, google-weather-api

I have found the longitude and latitude of my current location, now how to get Weather info from google api.

Please help!

Comment: Just try this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780836/using-google-weather-api-with-lat-and-lon-how-to-format

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Parth, just change the value and then paste the url in browser, then see the result

Comment: I think it gives the XML Feeds which you have to parse using XML Parsing and get the data that you require.

Comment: **The Google weather API was shut down in 2012** -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145820/google-weather-api-gone/35943521

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an answer to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951839/api-to-get-weather-based-on-longitude-and-latitude-coordinates) which shows usage of Google Weather API:

http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=,,,50500000,30500000

Comment: but just try for india and pakistan longitude and lotitude, then it is not working, why?

Comment: I googled it, found many link, but they are not working well, change the url which you have given and try for longitude and latitude of india, or pakistan.

Comment: @Veer for me http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=,,,19077693,72877808 and http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Mumbai,India give the same results. Can you provide an example where it's failing?

Answer (score 0):

You can check [here](http://meerutwala.com), they have implemented Google weather API